# values in a stringstream are not resetting after being taken from a vector

Tags: c++

I am trying to take the values of a vector and list them next to each other with an exclamation mark after each number.

Input is the long vector v= {3, 5, 6, 7};.

I would like the output to be 3! 4! 5! 6! 7!

My current output is 3! 34! 345! 3456! 34567!

```
string final_word = "", single_word; stringstream convert;
for (long i : v) {
  convert << i;
  single_word = convert.str();
  final_word += single_word;
  final_word += "! ";
  single_word = "";
  convert.clear();
return final_word;
```

Comment: `clear()` doesn't clear the contents of the stream, just the flags. Declare `convert` inside the loop, so a new instance is created each time through. And `single_word`, for that matter.

Comment: Also you either have a typo, or a misplaced `return`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thank you for the clarification, the clear() method was misinterpreted by me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to re-use a stringstream you also need to set its content to blank via `.str("")` as well as `.clear()`.

However it would be simpler to wait until the loop finishes before extracting the stream contents:

```
for (long i : v)
    convert << i << "! ";

return convert.str();
```

If you care about the trailing space you can add some code to remove the trailing space, e.g.:

```
auto final_word = convert.str();
if ( !final_word.empty() )
    final_word.resize( final_word.size() - 1 );
return final_word;
```

There are probably more elegant ways to do that ...